# unable to echo GET request in PHP

Tags: php

Following code supposed to grab the input value and print on screen, but I am not getting any result.

**index.php**

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['Submit'])){
  echo $_GET['fname'];
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>


<form action="index.php" method="GET">

  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
  
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

</html>
```

Comment: You need to add `name="Submit"` to the submit button, or `$_GET['Submit']` will be undefined.

Comment: Why not dump `$_GET` to see what it contains?

Comment: Mr.Eriksson has suggested correct answer,thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> An `<input type="submit">` element's value attribute contains a DOMString which is displayed as the button's label. Buttons do not have a true value otherwise.
> [reference]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/submit

This value is only for visual, If you want to receive a "Submit" field on the server then you will have to create a input hidden with name "Submit" and a default value, ex:

```
<form action="index.php" method="GET">

  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
  
  <!-- input to add data on the request -->
  <input type="hidden" id="Submit" name="Submit" value="1">

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

On the other hand, instead of verifying the presence of that field in the request, you can consult the $_GET content.

```php
if(!empty($_GET)){
  echo $_GET['fname'] ?? '';
}
```

or consult the specific parameter:

```php
if(!empty($_GET['fname'])){
  echo $_GET['fname'];
}
```

Comment: "This value is only for visual" — That's simply not true. The value will be submitted against the input's `name` if the submit button is used to submit the form. The problem here is that the input **doesn't have a name**.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['Submit'])){
  echo $_GET['fname'];
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<form action="index.php" method="GET">
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit">
</form> 

</html>

just added name="Submit" near <input type="submit"...
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. How is your code different from the one posted yesterday?